# Stablecoin as basic ERC-20 Token

Tags: solidity, erc-20, stablecoins

I am just trying to make a collateral backed stablecoin (1:1 AUD transparently backed) and am struggling to find any reasons as to why it cant be implemented using a simple ERC-20 contract?

If I offer 1:1 trade with the AUD on my website at ANY time then this should be enough to keep the token pegged to apprroximately $1 through the slight arbitrage trade acheiveable if it swings either way.

Am I missing something here? Is there any special functionality I need to implement for a stablecoin that isnt native to the ERC20 standard?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. A simple Erc20 that you mint, let’s say 1000 tokens, once you received a transfer of 1000 AUD would work.

It wouldn’t be a algorithmic stable coin, or even a decentralized stable coin, but it would work

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the insight!